# Why would SignalR drop out of WebSockets to LongPolling automatically?

Tags: azure, signalr

Experienced a problem recently with an Azure App Service where a Web Job froze for no apparent reason. Looking at what logs I could find, I saw that the Web Job, which is a SignalR client in this case, suddenly switched from WebSockets to LongPolling during SignalR protocol negotiation. The requests to the server were then 500's, and I have no further info as to why.

I suspect that something was going on on the VM (App Service Plan) that hosts these apps, and I am hoping that by understanding why SignalR might just switch protocols like that might shed some light.

The webjob is scheduled, runs every 5 minutes, and pumps file-read data (5 min files) to SignalR. For some reason the webjob just froze, did not run to completion. Cannot understand how that's even possible.

Comment: Have you found a solution to your problem?

Comment: Hi Wiktor we did not. It was quite some time ago now and I do not remember the conditions for this.